# Symfony4 store in session entity with relations

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4

I have a multi step form and need to store my entity in the session.The problem is that the entity have relations and when I retrieve it from Session, the relations attributes are disappearing (null).

I know I can serialize the entity and deserialize it, but it's a lot of checks/code with many relations...

```php
public function route1(Session $session, ....)
{
  $entity = new Entity();
  $form = $this->createForm(EntityType::class, $entity);
  $form->handleRequest($request);

  if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
     $session->set('entityData', $entity);

     dump($session->get('entityData')); // Here it's fine, nested attributes are still set

     return $this->redirectToRoute('route2');
  }
}


public function route2(Session $session)
{
    $entity = $this->em->merge($session->get('entityData'));
    dump($entity, $entity->getCustomer()->getFistname()); // And here all nested attributes are null like on the image ...
}
```

[image]

Comment: There's a [specific section](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/entities-in-session.html) in the manual about this. Although I think `merge()` is being removed in 3.0

Comment: already tried this but it's not working :/

Comment: Can you show some code? Have you tried accesing some data of the entity before dumping?

Comment: I've edited the original post:) @msg

Comment: Where's the `merge()` call?

Comment: edited again sorry